# Как залить на Github проект как один commit вместо сотни?

Tags: git, github

В начале идея:

допустим имеется проЭкт. Планируется, что он будет лежать по адресу

```
https://github.com/myProfile/test.git
```

Локально постоянно что-то делается, коммитится сотни раз в сотнях ветках. Далее заливается на гитхаб как версия 1.1. Далее исправляется 100 ошибок еще со 100 коммитами и заливается уже как версия 1.2 и т.д.

То есть у себя, как внутриразрабатываемого продукта, будет история с сотней-тысячей коммитов для отслеживания и отката (на всякий случай), а ТАМ (на гитхабе) история только "ver 1.1.", "ver 1.2 (что исправлено)", и т.д...

Можно ли это как-то сделать? Возможно ли?

Вот как примерно процесс происходит локально (кстати, может это уже неправильно, не знаю):

- создаю папку `test`
- набираю команду инициализации `git init`
- создаю какой-либо файл и добавляю `git add .`, `git commit -am "initial commit"`

И дальше пляска по сценарию:

1 шаг: создается ветка `git checkout -b develop20160731`

2 шаг: что-то делается и добавляется:

```
   git add .
   git commit -am "some comment"
   git checkout master
   git merge develop20160731
   git checkout develop20160731
```

3 шаг: повторяется шаг №2 N-раз.
       4 шаг: повторяется все с шага №1 уже с другой веткой

В итоге история выглядит как-то так:

```
* a0c188f 2016-07-31 | comment №2 for anotherBranch (HEAD -> master, anotherDevelop) [anonymous]
* 6acdde0 2016-07-31 | comment №1 for anotherBranch [anonymous]
* 9557ff9 2016-07-31 | comment №2 for my branch (develop20160731) [anonymous]
* b6946aa 2016-07-31 | comment №1 for my branch [anonymous]
* 864e4d9 2016-07-31 | initial commit [anonymous]
```

Нахожусь в мастере. И хочу все это отправить на *Github* как версию 1.1, т.е. в истории коммитов чтоб там был единственный одинокий коммит, что-то типа

```
Commits on Jul 31, 2016
  @anonymous
  added superProject v1.1
  anonymous committed 1 second ago
```

а не все коммиты проекта.

В следующий раз, чтоб добавился лишь еще один коммит `added superProject v1.2` из всех собранных коммитов локально и т.д.

Как так вытворить?

P.S. Если я как-то неправильно что-то делал локально, то прошу описать как правильнее. Хотелось бы, в идеале, полную инструкцию от и до "на пальцах"

Comment: Git под такие сценарии не заточен, хотя, чисто теоретически, что-то похожее можно сделать, просто трудоёмко. Историю выпрямляют с помощью rebase'ов, но не все команды разделяют мнение, что rebase'ы хороши. Commit'ы также можно объединять, но — к чему всё это? Сценарий Git'а — завести несколько веток типа `dev`, `stage`, `release` и сливать изменения из ветки в ветку по мере необходимости.

Comment: Вы вообще не хотите показывать публике промежуточные коммиты или вам достаточно обозначить те коммиты, которые являются релизными?

Comment: @NickVolynkin знать еще в чем разница) Но скорее первое, чтоб не было какой-либо головной боли у других при просмотре и скачивании, а доделалось что-то еще или нет, а когда сделается, а вдруг еще сырое, вон сколько коммитов, возможно еще правится, а вот этот баг исправлен? где он там в истории......... Чтоб видели только: ага вот версия 1, вот версия 2 где многое пофиксено, вон версия 3 и т.д. ничего лишнего

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Далее заливается на гитхаб как версия 1.1. Далее исправляется 100 ошибок еще со 100 коммитами и заливается уже как версия 1.2 и т.д.

Как правило, между версиями добавляется более чем одна фича или одно исправление ошибки. Сливать все исправления и дополнения в один коммит - неконструктивно. Потом сложно будет искать ошибки или ревертить изменения.

Если история у вас примерно такая:

```
c1fed68 попробуем сделать это так
a046d5b неа, не работает, давай по-другому
836f56c вроде нормально, давай пока сохраним несколько временных файлов
5edb66e пускай этот код не компилируется, но я иду домой, надо сохранить работу
8cb14a7 зря я вчера так написал, есть покрасивее способ
91c6c05 вот так зашибись
01c5594 вроде даже работает
```

То можно предложить следующий режим работы (он примерно соответствует методологии [git-flow](/questions/tagged/git-flow)):

1. В процессе работы над фичей разработчик делает отдельную ветку для фичи и в неё столько коммитов, сколько ему удобно.
2. Если содержимое таких веток вы тоже не хотите показывать, то можно завести второй, закрытый репозиторий, в котором будет вся "кухня", включая пулл-реквесты.
3. Ветки фич предлагаются к слиянию в develop, где копятся до релиза. В момент слияния ветка фичи схлапывается до 1 коммита (на выбор `git rebase -i`, `git reset --soft develop`), к коммиту пишется внятный комментарий. При этом привносить изменения в develop вы можете осуществлять как через слияние (merge), так и через rebase - это вопрос предпочтений команды. У обоих методов есть достоинства и недостатки.
4. Когда накопленные в develop фичи и багфиксы по вашим субъективным критериям должны стать релизом, происходят следующие шаги:

   1. Ветка develop сливается в master. С большой вероятностью будет возможен fast-forward, но если хотите и здесь сделать коммит слияния, используйте `git merge --no-ff develop`. Можно сконфигурировать Git, чтобы `--no-ff` подразумевалось для всех или только определённых веток - об этом подробнее в [ответе KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550710/181472).
   2. На полученный коммит вешается тег релиза. Обязательно используйте полновесный коммит (с комментарием).

      ```
      git tag 1.2.3 -m 'release 1.2.3'
      git push --follow-tags
      ```
   3. Если вы решили использовать два репозитория, сейчас самое время запушить в публичный.

      ```
      git push github --follow-tags
      ```

> Кстати, по похожей схеме реализована работа над такими крупными проектами как Linux. Там есть промежуточные ревьюеры, которые принимают к себе исключительно чистые, завершённые и упакованные коммиты, а потом проталкивают их дальше. А черновики не уходят дальше собственных репозиториев разработчиков.

В принципе, вы можете сливать все релизные коммиты в один перед пушем на публичный репозиторий. Однако, это чревато сложностями:

- Практически невозможно отследить коммит, который внёс ошибку.
- Нельзя отменить (`git revert`) конкретный коммит (т.е. фичу, правку и т.п.)
- Если вы захотите выпустить патч к версии, вам всё равно придётся выпускать его отдельным коммитом.
- Если кто-то со стороны предложит вам пулл-реквест с небольшими правками, то принять его и после влить в один большой коммит будет невежливо. Так вы фактически сотрёте информацию об авторстве кода.

Рекомендую остановиться на соответствии 1 фича - 1 коммит и дальше не объединять. Пользователи, даже не самые опытные, должны справиться с довольно несложным интерфейсом релизов на Github. А если в момент слияния ветки фичи есть какой-то код, который "неудобно" показывать публике - это признак того, что фича не готова.

Пример: [страница релизов самой программы Git](https://github.com/git/git/releases) даёт вполне наглядное представление о том, что является релизом:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, пройдет еще не один день прежде чем я до конца всё осознаю. Но  да, наверное в этом ключе буду думать лучше, чем косяпорить. Вроде логичный ход мыслей....Пока буду еще читать это несколько раз)) ... а по схеме Вадима получилось как обычно.... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550704/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-gihub-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-commit-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8#comment714314_550710

Comment: @АлексейШиманский возможно, я сложно объясняю? Мне кажется, у меня почти то же, но другими словами.

Comment: Не, дело не в теме, дело во мне :)))

Answer (score 9):

Сложно будет сделать так, что бы на github были одни коммиты, а у разработчиков - другие. Но можно сделать так, как делают в больших группах.

1. все фичи или багфиксы делаются в отдельной ветке. Даже мелкие. И не имеет значения, сколько там будет коммитов.
2. Все изменения тестируются в своих ветках. Если изменение не подошло, то ветку можно оставить или прибить (по желанию).
3. Когда фича/багфикс готов, его мержат в master/develop (это определяется текущим процессом и надобностями) с `no fast forward` (`git merge --no-ff` <ветка>). В этом случае в основной ветке будет как бы один коммит, но будет видно при необходимости все остальные. Такой коммит легко отревертить (`git revert -m 1 <sha хеш мержд коммита>`) (на самом деле это не просто реверт, а накатывания дифа изменений "наоборот", поэтому, если нужно, его можно откатить много раз - то есть, можно откатить откат отката).

`no fast forward` можно включить в конфиге, тогда не нужно будет даже указывать при мердже `git config --add merge.ff false` или `git config branch.master.mergeoptions  "--no-ff"` если нужно отключить только для мастера.

Подсумируем, на самом деле, похоже, Вам нужно только в конфиг добавить настройку и даже не нужно менять процесс.

Comment: что-то я не совсем то наверное делаю....у меня, к сожалению получилось по данной инструкции вот так http://i.stack.imgur.com/So2v7.jpg  и http://i.stack.imgur.com/wVrU0.jpg  .... в первом рисунке `merge --no-ff` делал только из `version1` и `version2` в `master`....а во втором и в них тоже `--no-ff` делал. ...наверное я не уловил мысль))

Comment: все правильно работает. На первом рисунке в мастере всего три коммита.

Comment: Ммм...Просто я желал чтоб как раз только эти три коммита и были отображены в гитхабе. Но наверное сам подход неверный) И надо изучать

Comment: возможно, Вам нужен сквошинг коммитов. Но его лучше делать, пока ещё на гитхаб (или другой удаленный репозиторий) код не залит. [Детальнее](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8). Но в этом случае локально эти коммиты также перетираются.

Comment: Да, про сквош знаю. Пока буду еще перечитывать и осознавать инфу (в т.ч. от Ника) и что я всё таки теперь хочу